# Why does my for loop not changes the colours when red is followed by green in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

So I am trying to change the class so that the method does not change any colours unless the list contains both red and green. For instance, `['red', 'Green']` should be changed to `['black', 'White']` as before, but `['red', 'red', 'yellow', 'Red']` should not be changed.

But when I run my code it just says KeyError "white". The code is below.

```
    class ColourChanger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.colour_replacement = {'red': 'black', 'green': 'white'}

    def make_readable(self, colours):
        result = []
        for col in colours:
            if "red".lower() and "green".lower() in colours:
                result.append(self.colour_replacement[col].title())
            else:
                result.append(col)
        return result

c = ColourChanger()
print(c.make_readable(['red', 'green', 'white', 'pink', 'yellow', 'red']))
print(c.make_readable(['red', 'Green']))
print(c.make_readable(['red', 'red', 'yellow', 'Red']))
```

Comment: `if "red".lower() in colours and "green".lower() in colours`. Your statement will always be `True` (and there is no need for `.lower()` for literal strings which are in lowercase anyway!)

Comment: in fact there are various other basic errors here, including the one which is resulting in the KeyError you're seeing

Comment: where is key value 'white', 'pink' and 'yellow'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to provide you an example what could work

```
class ColourChanger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.colour_replacement = {'red': 'black', 'green': 'white'}

    def make_readable(self, colours):
        result = []
        for col in colours:
            if 'red' in colours and 'green' in colours:
                try:
                    result.append(self.colour_replacement[col.lower()].title())
                except:
                    result.append(col.lower().title())
            else:
                result.append(col.title())
        return result

c = ColourChanger()
print(c.make_readable(['red', 'green', 'white', 'pink', 'yellow', 'red']))
print(c.make_readable(['red', 'Green']))
print(c.make_readable(['red', 'red', 'yellow', 'Red']))
```

Output

```
→ python3 color.py
['Black', 'White', 'White', 'Pink', 'Yellow', 'Black']
['Red', 'Green']
['Red', 'Red', 'Yellow', 'Red']
```

Comment: This would still end up throwing `KeyError` at `result.append(self.colour_replacement[col.lower()].title())` as there is no `white` key in `self.colour_replacement`.

Comment: The script works as there is a except to catch this KeyError, sure that's a really hacky way but should show a direction... Better would be a .get() and check if there is a key/value pair.

Comment: This is really cool! Thank you for the example. Had not thought about using the Try and except way. 
What if I want to replace red and green with black and white, no matter which case the letters are? 
So it works for; red, RED, Red and so on?

Comment: @shoesoles if the inputs are different, you'd use `upper()` or `lower()`, but in the case you provided, all of the strings were lower-case.

Comment: @e.maguire some of the "red" and "green" has istitle() and some are not. That is the ones I am having a hard time changing. 
I tried using: for col.lower() in colours:
But that did not work :(

Answer (score 1):

`if "red".lower() and "green".lower() in colours:`

Let's break this line down.

First of all, "red" and "green" are *already lowercase*. You don't need to call `lower()` on them.

Second of all, and more importantly, Python conditionals **are not compound.** If we break up your written conditional, we see that it consists of:

```
if "red".lower()
if "green".lower() in colours
```

In short, a conditional has to be written as such:

```
if "red" in colours and "green" in colours
```

Here's why: if we evaluate the two conditionals you wrote, we'd end up with *at least* one evaluating to True. `if "red".lower()` will *always evaluate as True* because it returns a non-null string, "red". So, instead of checking if "red" and "green" are both present in `colours`, you're only checking for "green".

As for your KeyError, that is being raised because there is no key called `white` in `colour_replacement`.

EDIT: I am not addressing what has already been discussed in the comments, only your primary issue with the conditional.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining the conditionals. I actually did not know that was hoe it worked.